# converting DateTime to String returns the wrong Date as a String

Tags: datetime, date, string, timezone, system

I have the following code to get the DateTime for EST Time Zone

```
Timezone tz = Timezone.getTimeZone('America/New_York');
DateTime now = Datetime.now();
Datetime localTime = now.addSeconds((tz.getOffset(now)/1000));
String timeString = String.valueOf(localTime);
```

The following debug logs return this

```
System.debug(localTime); // 2023-04-08 03:46:32 
System.debug(timeString); // 2023-04-07 23:46:32
```

The top System.debug is correct, the bottom one is wrong, i was expecting the same as the top just as a string

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct:

- `System.debug(datetime)` always shows the datetime in UTC
- [`String.valueOf(datetime)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_valueOf_2) converts it to your local time zone and returns that string

Since your time zone is New York (I guess), so UTC-4, the difference between the two System.debug is 4 hours.

Try `System.debug(String.valueOf(now));` and you'll see the same value of `System.debug(localTime);`